# Grails resources not found errors

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-resources-plugin

I have a grails application which stops working after installing `shiro plugin` for authentication. After installation I got the following error.

```
Error 2014-03-27 11:08:35,985 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator  - [RuntimeConfiguration] Unable to load beans from resources.groovy
Message: No signature of method: resources.executorService() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class, resources$_run_closure2) values: [class grails.plugin.executor.PersistenceContextExecutorWrapper, ...]
    Line | Method
->>   10 | run                       in resources
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    736 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    569 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    511 | invokeMethod              in     ''
|    334 | innerRun . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:43,300 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /js/select2.min.js
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:43,900 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /css/select2.css
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:43,961 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /css/application.css
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:44,033 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /js/dataTable/jquery.dataTables.js
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:44,106 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /js/dataTable/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:44,185 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /js/dataTable/dataTable_Bootstrap.js
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:44,260 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /css/datatable/jquery.dataTables.css
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:44,317 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /css/datatable/dataTable_bootstrap.css
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:44,384 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - Resource not found: /js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:46,513 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR resource.ResourceMeta  - While processing /css/scaffolding.css, a resource was required but not found: /plugins/twitter-bootstrap-2.3.0/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
| Error 2014-03-27 11:08:50,028 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: No such property: filters for class: securitySecurityFilters
Message: No such property: filters for class: securitySecurityFilters
```

I know resources are not found here but I have done nothing with the resources and directories, just installed the plugin and this error comes to show. I also tried to un-install the plugin and try again but that also did not solve my problem.

Comment: add this on your buildconfig.groovy
  build ':executor:0.3'

Comment: Did you run `grails shiro-quick-start` after installing the plugin, like the docs say?